# C# / ASP.Net / Json - Echo Nest

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm trying to allow a user to type an artist into a text box and then press a button to make a call to the Echo Nest API.

Here is a sample call:
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/playlist/basic?api_key=N6E4NIOVYMTHNDM8J&artist=Weezer&format=json&results=20&type=artist-radio

How would I construct the API call to include that information with the user input from the textbox. For example in the above call the the user input would be "Weezer".

Here is the link: http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/playlist.html

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to build the api call, I'm pretty sure I'd use ajax but not sure how exactly its done. Any idea?

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I tried it by using that but just couldnt get the format of the call right. It didnt return anything.

Comment: I think you probably just missed the fact that you need to use JSONP from the client.

Comment: In future I'd suggest adding what you've tried to your question and asking for specific help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses jQuery and assumes the following html.  Note that it also uses JSONP since you are making the request from the client to avoid cross domain security restrictions.  To make this work, I've changed the format type and added a callback.  The getJSON call uses the presence of the callback variable to inject an anonymous callback function that will call your actual callback.

```
 <label for="artist">Artist</label>
 <input type="text" id="artist" name="artist" />
 <button id="search-artist">Find</button>


 $('#search-artist').click( function() {
     var url = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/playlist/basic?api_key=N6E4NIOVYMTHNDM8J&artist="
                   +  $('#artist').val()
                   + "&results=20&type=artist-radio"
                   + "&format=jsonp&callback=?";
     $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
         // do something with the returned JSON data
     }
 });
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much. I'm trying to append the data (json) to_html to a div now. Although it doesn't seem to be working :\